# my symfony project not working on live server?

Tags: symfony, server

When i put my project on live server then the below page is showing.

[image]

Comment: Have you configured an Apache Virtual host, restarted apache and uploaded your project where the virtual host points to ? (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your site is here : http://offertenhammer.ch/web/app.php

that means you need to point the index to /web/app.php, in htaccess or vhost